# Version incompatibility between Spacy, Cuda, Pytorch and Python

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, spacy

I want run spacy in GPu. The configuration that I installed for the Spacy is defined below

Name: spacy

Version: 3.7.4

The Cuda configuration that have in my Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS based machine is

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243

I have a restriction to upgrade the Cuda. The PyTorch version that I have installed on the machine is "2.2.1+cu121" which have no support for the Cuda version I have.

I tried to downgrade the Pytorch and found that I need to downgrade the Python version as well.

My current python version is Python 3.12.2. If I go for a compatible Python version for pytorch that should be >=3.6,<3.7.0 for pytorch 1.4.0.

If I downgrade both Pytorch and Python that is not compatible with Spacy version.

I need to do a transformer-based NER task in Spacy. Therefore I am not sure what is the minimum requirement of spacy.

How can I handle this version incompatibility?

Comment: Anyone has any suggestions on this?